# How do I disable Cruciball?

Tags: peglin

Beating a run with a character unlocks a Cruciball option to increase difficulty. Is there a way to play a run without Cruciball once it's been unlocked? The lowest option I can select is Cruciball 1.

[image: Cruciball setting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the word Cruciball to toggle it on or off.

[image: Cruciball toggled off]

Comment: My game also shows a huge C next to Cruciball to turn it on and off

Comment: @Omniswitcher This was added in an update. Above screenshot is from an older version of the game.